# D3 scaleBand() resulting in path attribute error

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3 v4 and I am trying to use an [example](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/1ba11865ee0d0585f0274a0976324358) to create a new chart

The modifications I have made to the original chart are:

1. Used a scaleBand() instead of scaleTime() - in order to plot only weekdays
2. Changed the plotted curve from an area curve to a line
3. Hard coded the data directly into the page (to avoid CORS related errors)

Here is my modified code:

```
<!-- code is from: https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/1ba11865ee0d0585f0274a0976324358 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .line {
                fill: steelblue;
                clip-path: url(#clip);
            }

            .zoom {
                cursor: move;
                fill: none;
                pointer-events: all;
            }
        </style>
        <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        

        <script>
        const pricedata = [
  {
    "dt": "15 Dec 2020",
    "op": 133.7,
    "hi": 135.2,
    "lo": 131.75,
    "cl": 132.05,
    "adj": 132.05,
    "vol": "1,158,230"
  },
  {
    "dt": "14 Dec 2020",
    "op": 133,
    "hi": 138.9,
    "lo": 132.05,
    "cl": 134.75,
    "adj": 134.75,
    "vol": "8,933,077"
  },
  {
    "dt": "11 Dec 2020",
    "op": 136,
    "hi": 136.65,
    "lo": 129.25,
    "cl": 129.65,
    "adj": 129.65,
    "vol": "8,437,503"
  },
  {
    "dt": "10 Dec 2020",
    "op": 142,
    "hi": 143.5,
    "lo": 133.35,
    "cl": 136.75,
    "adj": 136.75,
    "vol": "10,062,738"
  },
  {
    "dt": "09 Dec 2020",
    "op": 138.1,
    "hi": 144.4,
    "lo": 137.93,
    "cl": 143,
    "adj": 143,
    "vol": "11,262,427"
  },
  {
    "dt": "08 Dec 2020",
    "op": 137.25,
    "hi": 139.75,
    "lo": 135.25,
    "cl": 137.15,
    "adj": 137.15,
    "vol": "7,236,160"
  },
  {
    "dt": "07 Dec 2020",
    "op": 143.1,
    "hi": 143.45,
    "lo": 136.79,
    "cl": 138.5,
    "adj": 138.5,
    "vol": "16,040,094"
  },
  {
    "dt": "04 Dec 2020",
    "op": 144.45,
    "hi": 146.7,
    "lo": 142,
    "cl": 142.5,
    "adj": 142.5,
    "vol": "20,987,485"
  },
  {
    "dt": "03 Dec 2020",
    "op": 136.05,
    "hi": 142.67,
    "lo": 135.1,
    "cl": 142.15,
    "adj": 142.15,
    "vol": "11,920,513"
  },
  {
    "dt": "02 Dec 2020",
    "op": 133.45,
    "hi": 135,
    "lo": 130.15,
    "cl": 135,
    "adj": 135,
    "vol": "10,223,921"
  },
  {
    "dt": "01 Dec 2020",
    "op": 126,
    "hi": 133.4,
    "lo": 125.5,
    "cl": 132.75,
    "adj": 132.75,
    "vol": "9,723,223"
  },
  {
    "dt": "30 Nov 2020",
    "op": 128.25,
    "hi": 131.3,
    "lo": 125.75,
    "cl": 125.75,
    "adj": 125.75,
    "vol": "9,568,687"
  },
  {
    "dt": "27 Nov 2020",
    "op": 128.1,
    "hi": 129.35,
    "lo": 125.69,
    "cl": 127.4,
    "adj": 127.4,
    "vol": "13,239,940"
  },
  {
    "dt": "26 Nov 2020",
    "op": 135.75,
    "hi": 136.46,
    "lo": 130,
    "cl": 130.2,
    "adj": 130.2,
    "vol": "8,373,964"
  },
  {
    "dt": "25 Nov 2020",
    "op": 140.4,
    "hi": 140.7,
    "lo": 133.7,
    "cl": 135.4,
    "adj": 135.4,
    "vol": "10,564,115"
  },
  {
    "dt": "24 Nov 2020",
    "op": 135.5,
    "hi": 140.6,
    "lo": 135.5,
    "cl": 140.3,
    "adj": 140.3,
    "vol": "12,663,546"
  },
  {
    "dt": "23 Nov 2020",
    "op": 134,
    "hi": 136.99,
    "lo": 132.45,
    "cl": 135.05,
    "adj": 135.05,
    "vol": "27,877,155"
  },
  {
    "dt": "20 Nov 2020",
    "op": 131.3,
    "hi": 135.5,
    "lo": 130.18,
    "cl": 132.6,
    "adj": 132.6,
    "vol": "13,918,358"
  },
  {
    "dt": "19 Nov 2020",
    "op": 129.65,
    "hi": 132.35,
    "lo": 128.8,
    "cl": 130.75,
    "adj": 130.75,
    "vol": "11,469,991"
  },
  {
    "dt": "18 Nov 2020",
    "op": 125.4,
    "hi": 132.2,
    "lo": 125.4,
    "cl": 132.2,
    "adj": 132.2,
    "vol": "14,009,691"
  },
  {
    "dt": "17 Nov 2020",
    "op": 127.55,
    "hi": 129.34,
    "lo": 125.95,
    "cl": 128.4,
    "adj": 128.4,
    "vol": "10,252,282"
  },
  {
    "dt": "16 Nov 2020",
    "op": 125,
    "hi": 128.45,
    "lo": 123.95,
    "cl": 126.5,
    "adj": 126.5,
    "vol": "11,281,500"
  },
  {
    "dt": "13 Nov 2020",
    "op": 120.65,
    "hi": 124.5,
    "lo": 119.5,
    "cl": 123.75,
    "adj": 123.75,
    "vol": "10,763,617"
  },
  {
    "dt": "12 Nov 2020",
    "op": 119.35,
    "hi": 122.59,
    "lo": 118.6,
    "cl": 121,
    "adj": 121,
    "vol": "10,520,933"
  },
  {
    "dt": "11 Nov 2020",
    "op": 119.55,
    "hi": 122.55,
    "lo": 116.4,
    "cl": 120.7,
    "adj": 120.7,
    "vol": "17,563,320"
  },
  {
    "dt": "10 Nov 2020",
    "op": 111.35,
    "hi": 123.5,
    "lo": 110.74,
    "cl": 120.45,
    "adj": 120.45,
    "vol": "32,038,342"
  },
  {
    "dt": "09 Nov 2020",
    "op": 97.16,
    "hi": 117.3,
    "lo": 97.16,
    "cl": 112.5,
    "adj": 112.5,
    "vol": "33,591,091"
  },
  {
    "dt": "06 Nov 2020",
    "op": 95.08,
    "hi": 98.44,
    "lo": 94.64,
    "cl": 96.18,
    "adj": 96.18,
    "vol": "12,902,167"
  },
  {
    "dt": "05 Nov 2020",
    "op": 98.02,
    "hi": 98.22,
    "lo": 94.28,
    "cl": 95.9,
    "adj": 95.9,
    "vol": "9,951,931"
  },
  {
    "dt": "04 Nov 2020",
    "op": 94.82,
    "hi": 98.42,
    "lo": 91.85,
    "cl": 96.5,
    "adj": 96.5,
    "vol": "13,958,508"
  },
  {
    "dt": "03 Nov 2020",
    "op": 91.44,
    "hi": 94.02,
    "lo": 90.74,
    "cl": 92,
    "adj": 92,
    "vol": "9,987,164"
  },
  {
    "dt": "02 Nov 2020",
    "op": 88.96,
    "hi": 91.84,
    "lo": 86.55,
    "cl": 90.52,
    "adj": 90.52,
    "vol": "7,279,269"
  },
  {
    "dt": "30 Oct 2020",
    "op": 88.56,
    "hi": 90.55,
    "lo": 86.44,
    "cl": 89.14,
    "adj": 89.14,
    "vol": "11,586,654"
  },
  {
    "dt": "29 Oct 2020",
    "op": 92.4,
    "hi": 92.58,
    "lo": 88.28,
    "cl": 88.72,
    "adj": 88.72,
    "vol": "12,337,941"
  },
  {
    "dt": "28 Oct 2020",
    "op": 92.58,
    "hi": 93.27,
    "lo": 89.4,
    "cl": 91.5,
    "adj": 91.5,
    "vol": "11,967,865"
  },
  {
    "dt": "27 Oct 2020",
    "op": 95.3,
    "hi": 96.04,
    "lo": 92.97,
    "cl": 93.46,
    "adj": 93.46,
    "vol": "14,907,344"
  },
  {
    "dt": "26 Oct 2020",
    "op": 96.4,
    "hi": 100.2,
    "lo": 95.24,
    "cl": 95.24,
    "adj": 95.24,
    "vol": "6,958,130"
  },
  {
    "dt": "23 Oct 2020",
    "op": 97.54,
    "hi": 100.15,
    "lo": 96.5,
    "cl": 97.84,
    "adj": 97.84,
    "vol": "12,581,866"
  },
  {
    "dt": "22 Oct 2020",
    "op": 93,
    "hi": 97.98,
    "lo": 93,
    "cl": 97.66,
    "adj": 97.66,
    "vol": "8,312,519"
  },
  {
    "dt": "21 Oct 2020",
    "op": 93.38,
    "hi": 96.44,
    "lo": 92.98,
    "cl": 95.1,
    "adj": 95.1,
    "vol": "10,556,543"
  },
  {
    "dt": "20 Oct 2020",
    "op": 91.1,
    "hi": 93.66,
    "lo": 91.1,
    "cl": 92.56,
    "adj": 92.56,
    "vol": "8,624,783"
  },
  {
    "dt": "19 Oct 2020",
    "op": 91.5,
    "hi": 93.08,
    "lo": 91.3,
    "cl": 92.56,
    "adj": 92.56,
    "vol": "6,989,064"
  },
  {
    "dt": "16 Oct 2020",
    "op": 92.32,
    "hi": 94.4,
    "lo": 90.82,
    "cl": 91.16,
    "adj": 91.16,
    "vol": "10,976,679"
  },
  {
    "dt": "15 Oct 2020",
    "op": 94.2,
    "hi": 95.32,
    "lo": 91.52,
    "cl": 92,
    "adj": 92,
    "vol": "16,485,788"
  },
  {
    "dt": "14 Oct 2020",
    "op": 94.7,
    "hi": 95.98,
    "lo": 93.26,
    "cl": 94.2,
    "adj": 94.2,
    "vol": "10,562,462"
  },
  {
    "dt": "13 Oct 2020",
    "op": 97.66,
    "hi": 98.46,
    "lo": 93.28,
    "cl": 94.82,
    "adj": 94.82,
    "vol": "14,119,377"
  },
  {
    "dt": "12 Oct 2020",
    "op": 99,
    "hi": 100.35,
    "lo": 97.4,
    "cl": 97.54,
    "adj": 97.54,
    "vol": "7,174,030"
  },
  {
    "dt": "16 Jan 2020",
    "op": 180,
    "hi": 184.35,
    "lo": 179.9,
    "cl": 184.1,
    "adj": 184.1,
    "vol": "12,533,036"
  },
  {
    "dt": "15 Jan 2020",
    "op": 184.7,
    "hi": 185.25,
    "lo": 180.09,
    "cl": 180.85,
    "adj": 180.85,
    "vol": "12,612,188"
  },
];
        /* Format data */
        const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d %b %Y");

        const data = pricedata;
        data.forEach(function(d, i){
            d = format_data(d);
        });  

        const svg = d3.select("svg"),
            margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 40},
            margin2 = {top: 430, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
            width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;


        /* One of the subtleties of plotting stock data is that markets are only open on weekdays: 
            if you were to plot the behavior of a stock using a time scale, you’d see distracting 
            gaps every weekend. This chart therefore uses a band scale whose domain is every weekday 
            in the dataset. A few gaps remain for holiday weekdays, such as Christmas, 
            but these are infrequent and allow the labelling of Mondays.*/

       const x = d3.scaleBand()
                    .domain(d3.utcDay
                        .range(data[0].dt, +data[data.length - 1].dt + 1)
                        .filter(d => d.getUTCDay() !== 0 && d.getUTCDay() !== 6))
                    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
                    .padding(0.2);

        const x2 = d3.scaleBand()
                    .domain(d3.utcDay
                        .range(data[0].dt, +data[data.length - 1].dt + 1)
                        .filter(d => d.getUTCDay() !== 0 && d.getUTCDay() !== 6))
                    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
                    .padding(0.2);     

        /* const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
            x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]), */
        const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
              y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
              xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
              yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

        const brush = d3.brushX()
                          .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
                          .on("brush end", brushed);

        const zoom = d3.zoom()
                      .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
                      .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
                      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
                      .on("zoom", zoomed);

        const line = d3.line()
                      .x(function(d) { return x(d.dt); })
                      .y(function(d) { return y(d.hi); });   
            
        const line2 = d3.line()
                      .x(function(d) { return x(d.dt); })
                      .y(function(d) { return y(d.hi); });              

            /*
        const area = d3.area()
            .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.dt); })
            .y0(height)
            .y1(function(d) { return y(d.cl); });

        const area2 = d3.area()
            .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
            .x(function(d) { return x2(d.dt); })
            .y0(height2)
            .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.cl); }); */

        svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var focus = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "focus")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var context = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "context")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");
            
        var identity = d3.zoomIdentity;

        ///
        /*d3.csv("sp500.csv", type, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error; */

        //x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dt; }));
        //y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.cl; })]);
        x2.domain(x.domain());
        y2.domain(y.domain());

        focus.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);

        focus.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        focus.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
            .call(yAxis);

        context.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line2);

        context.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
            .call(xAxis2);

        context.append("g")
            .attr("class", "brush")
            .call(brush)
            .call(brush.move, x.range());

        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "zoom")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .call(zoom);
        /* }); */
        ///


        function brushed() {
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") 
            return; // ignore brush-by-zoom

        let s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
        x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
        focus.select(".area").attr("d", line);
        focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
            .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
            .translate(-s[0], 0));           
        }

        function zoomed() {
            if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") 
                return; // ignore zoom-by-brush

            let t = d3.event.transform;
            transform = t;
            console.log(d3.event.transform);
            x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
            focus.select(".area").attr("d", line);
            focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
            context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
        }

        function format_data(d) {
            d.dt = parseDate(d.dt);
            d.op = +d.op;
            d.hi = +d.hi;
            d.lo = +d.lo;
            d.cl = +d.cl;
            d.adj = +d.adj;
            d.vol = +d.vol;
            return d;
        }


        d3.select("body")
        .on("keypress", function() {
            // zoom out
            if (d3.event.key == "s") {
                var x0 = x2(x.domain()[0]);
                var x1 = x2(x.domain()[1]);
                var currentDifference = Math.abs(x0-x1);
                
                x0 -= currentDifference / 2 / 3
                x1 += currentDifference / 2 / 3
                
                updateBrushAndZoom(x0,x1);
            }
            // zoom in
            else if (d3.event.key == "w") {
                var x0 = x2(x.domain()[0]);
                var x1 = x2(x.domain()[1]);
                var currentDifference = Math.abs(x0-x1);
                
                x0 += currentDifference / 2 / 3
                x1 -= currentDifference / 2 / 3
                
                updateBrushAndZoom(x0,x1);
            }
            // pan left:
            else if (d3.event.key == "a") {
                var x0 = x2(x.domain()[0]);
                var x1 = x2(x.domain()[1]);
                    
                var currentDifference = Math.abs(x0-x1);
                
                x0 -= currentDifference / 2 / 3
                x1 -= currentDifference / 2 / 3

                updateBrushAndZoom(x0,x1);
            }
            // pan right
            else if (d3.event.key == "d") {
                var x0 = x2(x.domain()[0]);
                var x1 = x2(x.domain()[1]);
                var currentDifference = Math.abs(x0-x1);
                
                x0 += currentDifference / 2 / 3;
                x1 += currentDifference / 2 / 3;

                updateBrushAndZoom(x0,x1);
            }
            
        })
        
        
        function updateBrushAndZoom(x0,x1) {
            if (x0 < x2.range()[0]) x0 = x2.range()[0];
            if (x1 > x2.range()[1]) x1 = x2.range()[1];
            
            x.domain([x0,x1].map(x2.invert, x2));
            focus.select(".area").attr("d", line);
            focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
                
            var identity = d3.zoomIdentity
            .scale(width/ (x1 - x0))
            .translate(-x0, 0);
                
            context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(identity.invertX, identity));  
            svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, identity);
        }


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I load this page in my browser, I get the following error:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,-49653.99999…".
(anonymous) @ d3.v4.min.js:2
each @ d3.v4.min.js:2
attr @ d3.v4.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ brush_example.html:2327
d3.v4.min.js:2 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,-49653.99999…".
(anonymous) @ d3.v4.min.js:2
each @ d3.v4.min.js:2
attr @ d3.v4.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ brush_example.html:2341
brush_example.html:2368 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SVGGElement.brushed (brush_example.html:2368)
    at k.apply (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at it (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at o.emit (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at o.brush (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at ut.each (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at Kn.e.move (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at ut.call (d3.v4.min.js:2)
```

I have no idea what is causing this, as the error is not very informative - and appears to be being raised deep inside D3's internals.

How can I fix the code so that I use the correct scale type and also change the plotted chart type?

Answer (score 1):

I started working my way through this but there's just too many issues to wade through.

First, this:

```
d3.utcDay
  .range(data[0].dt, +data[data.length - 1].dt + 1)
  .filter(d => d.getUTCDay() !== 0 && d.getUTCDay() !== 6)
```

is returning an empty array.  Your data is sorted DESC and that `.range` is expecting the first argument to be before the second.

But even if you correct that, this:

```
x(d.dt)
```

Will still return `NaN` because your scale band will have discreet UTC dates that aren't in your dataset.  My timezone is -5, so here's the domain:

[image]

While my data looks like this:

[image]

See the mismatch?

So, if you conquered those two issues, the next thing I noticed is you don't set a domain on the y-axis, you need something like this:

```
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.hi; })]);
  y2.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.hi; })]);
```

But even if you got that far, it looks like the y2 height is off and I'm seeing errors in the brushed events.

For what's it worth, this is as far as I got on [cleaning it up](https://plnkr.co/edit/wIdnmvZRzBfYaCxl?preview).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Mark, I think at this point, I have to concede that D3 is not the tool for the job. The learning curve is too steep, and I have tight deadlines to meet. Ill probably settle for something like ChartJs, to quickly get out the charting I want done. But, thanks for your effort - if nothing else, it has helped convince me to abandon D3 for my current project.